# ubuntu ppa's and apt precedence

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, aptitude

I'm trying to get the latest mplayer installed with vdpau support.  Haven't had any luck so far.

I found a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rvm/+archive/mplayer) that says it works and I want to install it.  I added the PPA to my *apt.sources* and did an update.

I just wanted to know, how do I know that I'm now installing the mplayer package from the PPA, and not Ubuntu's standard repositories?  From what I see I just install the same package using `apt-get install mplayer`.

How do I know which mplayer I'm getting?  Where do I specify what takes precedence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apt-cache policy mplayer
```

Look at the Candidate line, and then find that version in the below list.

Comment: brilliant thx!!

Answer (score 0):

`apt-cache show mplayer` will show some info on the package, including version (but not repo).

When you install a package, if there are multiple candidates, the one with the highest version number is installed by default. You can 'pin' a package to a certain version (or maybe a certain repo?), but I don't know how. Google it.

Finally, `apt-cache policy mplayer` is a good way to see the different candidates, as noted above.